# Need help declaring and assigning multidimensional arrays with different numbers of elements in Python (v Java)

Tags: java, python, arrays, numpy, dynamic-arrays

I am a long time java user diving into python.
I am searching for a way to create multi-dim arrays that may not have the same number of elements, some or all are NOT known until run time.

In java I'd assign a 3 dimensional array named runSet like this below:

```
double[][][] runSet = new double[5][][];

int randomInt = genRandInt();  // Returns a random integer between 0 and 101.

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) runSet[i] = getRuns(randomInt);  // Returns double[randomInt][ToBeDetermined]

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

public double[][] getRuns(int num)
{  
  double[][] array2D = new double[num][];
  for(int i = 0; i< num; i++) array2D[i] = genRandArray(); // returns double[] of random values with length between 0 and 1001.
  
  return array2D; // Returns double[num][Varying Length]
} // end GetRuns()
```

No problems, this works just fine.
BUT using python I want to do the same, and I cannot figure out how to properly assign arrays with unknown number of elements.  The best I have been able to come up with is:

```
import numpy as np
    
runSet = np.empty([5, ]) # <--- Does NOT throw an error.
randomInt = genRandInt()   # Returns a random integer between 0 and whatever.

i = 0
while i < 4:
   runSet[i] = getRuns(randomInt)  # Returns [][] (double[randomInt][ToBeDetermined] in java speak)
   i += 1

#-------------------------------------------------
    
def getRuns(num) 
    array2D = np.empty([num, ]) # <-- Does NOT throw an error.
    i = 0
    while i < num:
         array2D[i] = genRandArray(); # Returns double[] of random values with a random LENGTH as well.
         i += 1
          
    return array2D; // Returns double[num][Varying Length]
    
# end GetRuns()
```

In genRandArray(), python version, I am returning with this (example random) statement:

```
return [12.4, 6.4, 8.0, 7.9, 8.2, 6.3, 8.8, 3.14, 2.345, 66.828, 12.0]
```

In both places I assign runSet[i] & array2D[i], I now know I'll get the error kind of like "sequential list being added to single ...."

Question 1): Maybe an array form is better for the return?

Question 2): Am I even close?
I have the feeling I may be going about this the completely wrong way, as the array thinking in python seems totally bass akward from the way I've been trained to think about it in java.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Looks like `python` lists would match your Java case better, since they can contain lists that differ in length, and can be created on-the-fly.  `numpy` arrays cannot be ragged.  A (n,m,p) shaped array has `p` length arrays in the inner most dimension, not a variable number.

Comment: I have been focused on arrays, as I am very comfortable with them in java, and my impression of python lists is that they are looked down upon as being slower and more memory needy. I am going to look more at lists, thanks.

Comment: `numpy` arrays are faster (for some things) and memory efficient because they store numeric values as bytes (not pointers) in a 1d array, and reference it multidimensionally with `shape` and `strides`.  As long as it's using compiled methods that work with whole arrays it is fast.  But for storing general objects (references) and iterative processing lists are better.

Comment: `np.empty([5, , ])` produces a syntax error. The double commas is wrong.  What's it supposed to mean?  `[5,]` in the next block doesn't produce an error, but the comma suggests you've misunderstood Python lists, tuples, and numpy shape.  I'd suggest more study of Python and numpy basics before trying to do anything fancy.

Comment: Yeah, just a single comma was meant. Fixed.

Comment: A comma in a `(5,)` creates a single element tuple.  `[5]` is a single element list, no comma needed.  Either can be used to create an 1d numpy array.  Or even `np.zeros(5)`.   In any case, the comma is part of Python tuple syntax; it does not have a special `numpy` meaning (`numpy` does not extend Python syntax).

Comment: I have been looking over my code, and see I've used a mix of array and lists. Years of java arrays (and strict type definitions) has caught me back on my heals!  I can't believe I got as far as I did before I ran into this issue.  I have to admit, this is the stuff that makes me miss those strict type definitions. Pressing on...